# What kind of food is 漢巴德? (from 官場現形記)

Tags: loanwords, transcription

In the Qing dynasty novel [官場現形記](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanchang_Xianxing_Ji), there is [this passage](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hant/%E5%AE%98%E5%A0%B4%E7%8F%BE%E5%BD%A2%E8%A8%98/%E7%AC%AC007%E5%9B%9E):

> 三荷包接過看時，只見上面開的是：清牛湯、炙鰣魚、冰蠶阿、丁灣羊肉、**漢巴德**、牛排、凍豬腳、橙子冰忌廉、澳洲翠鳥雞、龜仔蘆筍、生菜英腿、加利蛋飯、白浪布丁（10300620）、濱格、豬古辣冰忌廉、葡萄乾、香蕉、咖啡。另外幾樣酒是：勃蘭地、魏司格、紅酒、巴德、香檳，外帶甜水、鹹水。

which is a menu for a Western-style banquet. It seems that many items are based on older styles of transcription, for example 豬古辣冰忌廉 (chocolate ice-cream) would be 巧克力冰激凌 in Mandarin today.

What kind of food is 漢巴德 referring to? It seems vaguely similar to "hamburger", and [this article](http://tastespirit.com/p/23645.html) thinks so too - "估计是汉堡", but I'm not sure. Can anyone confirm, or find another source?

Comment: 白浪布丁 = blancmange 吧!

Answer (score 1):

A hilarious passage.  My edition says 漢巴德牛排 (no comma), if that's correct it's some kind of beefsteak; in the wine list there's a 巴德, could be related, beef steak with a wine based sauce? The article suggests port for 巴德, why not bordeaux? All guesses on my part.

Some of the other dishes also look mangled: 澳洲翠鳥雞 the Australian kingfisher chicken surely should have a comma before chicken.

If you get a complete translation, please put it up here!